# Choose a value from 4 columns in R

Tags: r

I want to to check 4 columns in a dataframe and take the value from either col1,col2,col3, or col4. Below for loop and if/else works. However, I wish to ask how to do it in R in a more efficient manner?

```
for (j in 1:nrow(df)){

  
  if(is.na(df[j,"Name.A"])){
  
      if(is.na(df[j,"Name.B"])){
    
          if(is.na(df[j,"Name.C"])){
        
              df[j,"Name"] = df[j,"Name.D"]
          
          } else{
            
            df[j,"Name"] = df[j,"Name.C"]
            }  
      
      }else{
        
        df[j,"Name"] = df[j,"Name.B"]
        
        }
   
   }else {
     
     df[j,"Name"] = df[j,"Name.A"]
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `coalesc` to grab first non-NA value with `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(
  Name.A = c(NA, NA, NA, 1),
  Name.B = c(NA, NA, 2, 2),
  Name.C = c(NA, 3, 3, 3),
  Name.D = c(4, 4, 4, 4))


df %>%  mutate(name = coalesce(Name.A, Name.B, Name.C, Name.D))

  Name.A Name.B Name.C Name.D name
1     NA     NA     NA      4    4
2     NA     NA      3      4    3
3     NA      2      3      4    2
4      1      2      3      4    1
```

Comment: That’s much simpler and more tidy! Thanks!